# javascript alert in asp.net problem

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, alert

i am calling a javascript alert but the background screen becomes white rather than leaving the current screen and doing a pop up?

i solved this by implementing the following in the sitemaster and creating a hidden field to call from the program

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var alertMsg = document.getElementById('MainContent_errorMessageHidden');
                if (alertMsg != null) alert(alertMsg.value); 
            </script>
```

the problem with this is when i run the program normally it does not work, when i run it through debugger with breakpoints it works fine, i cant understand why,

this is what i have in the aspx file where the alert will show:

asp:HiddenField Value="" ID="errorMessageHidden" runat="server" Visible="false"

and in the method calling the alert:

```
    private void Alert(string p)
    {

        errorMessageHidden.Visible = true;
        errorMessageHidden.Value = p;

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: What does the DOM of your page look like?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to clean cache
2. Try to alert("1") instead of dom element

Comment: i cleaned cache, what do you mean when you say DOM? oh and i changed the alert message too but it shows me the new message but in the wrong alert type

Comment: When you change the message , you have the same behaviour ?

Comment: Did you remove if as well . I think it happens because if conditions

Comment: i removed the if but still same problem, not sure why this is happening